# Unable to load nvm commands via SSH [Ubuntu 14]

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I know there are quite a few similar questions around, but I am still unable to get this to work.

If I try to run `nvm install node`, all starts to work again.

```
ubuntu@*:~$ node
The program 'node' can be found in the following packages:
 * node
 * nodejs-legacy
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
ubuntu@*:~$ npm
The program 'npm' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install npm
ubuntu@*:~$ forever
forever: command not found
ubuntu@*:~$ source ~/.profile
ubuntu@*:~$ source ~/.bash_profile
-bash: /home/ubuntu/.bash_profile: No such file or directory
ubuntu@*:~$ nvm install node
v5.5.0 is already installed.
Now using node v5.5.0 (npm v3.7.1)
ubuntu@*:~$ which npm
/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v5.5.0/bin/npm
ubuntu@*:~$ which node
/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v5.5.0/bin/node
ubuntu@*:~$ which forever
/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v5.5.0/bin/forever
ubuntu@*:~$
```

I also tried to do `nvm alias default 5.5.0`  but with no success :(

If anybody can help that would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I realised that I could solve the problem by adding `nvm use 5.5.0` to my `.bashrc`